# The manuscript Summa Logicae (William of Ockham)

Tags: academic-writing

The *Summa Logicae* (Latin, in English it's *the Sum of Logic*) is a textbook on logic by [William of Ockham](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_S5dFdpF6xm0/SuC3NlxHmwI/AAAAAAAAAj4/zGiXgFk3NK0/s400/William-of-Ockham-Moscarlop-GNU-free.png). There are articles about *the Summa Logicae* [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_logicae)  and [in Logicmuseum](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Summa_Logicae_%28Ockham%29).

It was published in Paris in 1488. There are different typed variants of this textbook, for example [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Ockham.Summa_logicae.pdf) (in English).

But I can't find any scans or photos of the original handmade manuscript or the original (first) edition. Do you know any links or libraries or museims, where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

[Yale Digital Content](http://discover.odai.yale.edu/ydc/Record/3471469/Description#tabs) reports that it holds:

> William of Ockham, Summa Logicae, etc. General Collection, Beinecke Rare Book and Manuscript Library, Yale University.
>
> Manuscript on paper (thick, coarse, some deckle edges; watermarks indistinguishable) of William of Ockham, Summa logicae. With Walter Burley, De puritate artis logicae tractatus brevior, beginning of text only.
>
> Creator:   William, of Ockham, ca. 1285-ca. 1349.
> Publisher:   Italy,
> Publication Date:    [between 1400 and 1450]
> Type:    Archives or manuscripts
> Physical Description:    ff. i + 125 + i: paper ; 222 x 145 (195 x 110) mm.

Note that it is desribed as *Written by a single scribe in small, cramped and highly abbreviated gothic cursive*, so it is presumably not a "first edition". But given that it apparently predates your date for first publication (1488?), it may be useful.